# what is this device sticked on my car dashboard

Tags: tata

I brought an used car , and there is an device sticked on dashboard. What is this device?[image]

Comment: Possibly a microphone for a hands-free phone.

Comment: In the reflection off the glass, the logo is rather like the Tata logo (as tagged), so it might be a standard part. There also appears to be a word 'above' it which I cab't make out.

Comment: @HandyHowie - I think you're exactly right about it being a microphone.

Comment: I have an aftermarket digital rearview mirror and dash cam. It has a separate GPS unit. This is where the instructions tell me to mount the GPS unit. It would have a wire tucked in around the windshield and come out above the rear view mirror if that's what it is.

Comment: @HandyHowie, It might not be microphone because my car has inbuilld microphone on the center console on the celing